# Why is ChromeDriver not storing Cache when Quit is called in Headless mode?

Tags: java, c#, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using the argument `--user-data-dir=CacheData` to save the Chrome session. But it only gets saved when the Chrome window is closed. When i call `driver.Quit();` in Headless mode the session doesn't get saved because i assume that Chrome is just being killed. **It works in non-headless mode.**

Is there any way to save the session before quitting?

Code:

```
ChromeDriverService service = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService(driverPath);
service.HideCommandPromptWindow = false;

ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions()
options.AddArgument("--user-data-dir=UserData");

chrome = new ChromeDriver(service, options);

//does stuff that i want to store in userdata

chrome.Quit();
//kills chrome and chrome doesnt store the userdata, only when i close the //window with the x
```

Comment: Code trials please?

Comment: @DebanjanB I added it